# SOS !! Пожалуйста,помогите с методом заполнения данных

Tags: python

Вопрос в следующем,что делать ***если файл условно "бесконечен" то бишь значения в него добавляются на ходу,как переделать код*** ? Безусловно я примерно понимаю ,как это реализовать,но очень поможет " рука мастера " дабы потом разобрался с участком кода и в целом получил опыт.

***код выполняет следующую задачу*** :
Написать программу, которая читая последовательность чисел из файла, выводит на экран самую длинную возрастающую последовательность, ее длину и позицию (в числах и символах) с которой она началась.

```py
import time, os, string, psutil, re

start_time = time.time()
symbol_len = 1  # Размер буфера чтения
with open('111.txt','r+') as file:
    a = str(file.read())
    s = re.sub('[^\d]', '', a)
if  os.stat("111.txt").st_size == 0 :
    print("Файл пуст   !!!")
else:
    print("Введена последовоательность :",s)
    res = ''
    res_list = []
    i = 0

    while i < len(s):
        if res == '' or (int(res[-1]) < int(s[i])):
            res += s[i]
        else:
            res_list.append(res)
            res = s[i]
        i += 1

    res_list.append(res)
    _max = max(res_list, key=len)
    print(f'Самая длинная восх. посл. - {_max}\nсимволов - {len(_max)}\nначальный индекс - {s.find(_max)}')
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    print("Программа занимает ", process.memory_info().rss /1048576,"мбайт")  # in bytes
    print("--- %s Секунд выполнялась программа  ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Вот и приведите тут примерную реализацию, чтобы какой-нибудь из мастеров мог прокомментировать.

Comment: https://medium.com/@aliasav/how-follow-a-file-in-python-tail-f-in-python-bca026a901cf Вот это почитайте, думаю что поможет. Если я правильно понимаю Вам нужна реализация `tail -f` на `python`

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/tailer/  Вот эту библиотеку еще глянте

Answer (score 0):

а не подойдет такой алгоритм:

позиция в файле = 0

в цикле если размер файла изменился

1. открыть файл
2. перейти с помощью seek на старую позицию
3. считать данные с позиции до конца файла
4. обработать данные
5. закрыть файл
6. запомнить новую позицию в файле